# Button in the middle of 2 sections with CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 sections and I'm trying to put a button in the middle of them. But something is going wrong and I don't know what it is. Here is the code:

```html
<section style="background: #000; color: #FFF; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;">
  <p>This is the content.</p>
  <div style="width: 80px; padding: 20px; display: table; position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, 50%); background:red">Button</div>
</section>

<section style="background: #444; color: #FFF; position: relative; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;">
  <p>This is another content.</p>
</section>
```

I've tried to put "z-index" property in DIV style, but it also didn't work. It cuts and the DIV stay back of next section. So... how can I bring DIV back to front of the both sections? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you've set `overflow: hidden;` to the containers so it's hiding anything that overflows it regardless of the position attributes. Change your HTML to this *although I'd advise putting the styling into a CSS file to make it easier to manage*.

```html
<section style="background: #000;color: #FFF;position: relative;margin: 0;padding: 0;float: left;width: 100%;">
  <p>This is the content.</p>
  <div style="z-index: 9999;width: 80px;padding: 20px;display: table;position: absolute;bottom: 0;left: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, 50%);background:red;">Button</div>
</section>

<section style="background: #444;color: #FFF;position: relative;margin: 0;padding: 0;width: 100%;float: left;">
  <p>This is another content.</p>
</section>
```

I've added a `width: 100%;` and `float: left;` to both container elements and removed the `overflow: hidden;` from each. Additionally I've added a `z-index: 9999;` to the button as well.

Comment: Thank you, it worked well... I've forget about overflow, it will be needed to me in some sections, but I will avoid keeping it in sections where I need to expand content outside the limits. And it was just a example code I know about styling into a CSS file.

Comment: Not a problem, when you have a chance; as this solution worked please accept the answer.